# Remove only duplicates from specific Postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which contains duplicates and I would like to keep only one row for each duplicates.

I can select duplicates with my SQL command :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (email, first_name, last_name) * from customer;
```

But I would like to use `DELETE` with my previous command.

This command should work right ?

```
DELETE FROM customer WHERE customer.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT id FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT ON (email, first_name, last_name) * from customer));
```

Is it true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a `id` field.

```
delete from customer 
where id not in (
    select min(id)
    from customer
    group by email, first_name, last_name
)
```

The subquery finds the id of the rows you want to keep.
Then you delete the other rows

Comment: Yes it works fine ! My query didn't work because I need to add an alias I assume. Thank you anyway ! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. I can't find your `ID` in `(SELECT DISTINCT ON (email, first_name, last_name) * from customer));`
2. The  `distinct on` only return the first row of the duplication data that is unpredictable